# how to set focus on the text after validating it in JSF

Tags: jsf

I have a convertDateTime="MM/yyyy" in my inputText field, which looks like#

```
<%taglib uri ="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefis"h"/>
<%taglib uri ="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefis"f"/>

<h:outputLabel value=#{prop.fromLabel}" for="dateText" id="frmDateId">
<h:inputText id="id" value="Bean.details.fromDate" binding="#{Bean.fromDateInputText}">
<f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/yyyy"/>
</h:inputText>
<h:message for="dateText" errorClass="errorMessage"/>
</h:outputLabel>
```

I want to set focus for the error message i have set for the properties error message.   I am not able to reach bean to set focus as the error is on JSF validation level so unable to setFocus for the component Id. Please help.

Thanks
Mac

Comment: First, welcome to Stackoverflow. Second, your code isn't valid JSF. Is this a copy&paste error? Third, "setting focus for the error message" isn't really possible, as it's plain text. Do you want to focus the `<h:inputText/>`?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for WLC.  Yeah . I was looking to set the focus on input Text as this has a calendar entry attached to it.  The code is not upto mark 'coz I have hand written from other machine. I have set the "Javax.faces.converter.DateTimeconverter.DATE = Error ! Invalid Date format".  Now the Issue is that after the validation , I want to set the focus on the Input Text.

Comment: Can you provide the original code? Or at least, fix it. The tags should be preffixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're free to add omnifaces to your project, I'd suggest adding [o:highlight](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/highlight) to your base template. It will automatically add a CSS class to invalid components and focus the first such element.

---

If you need plain JSF, you need to do it yourself, here's an example:

```
<h:inputText id="dateIn" styleClass="#{component.valid ? '' : 'invalidInput'}" 
        value="#{bean.details.fromDate}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/yyyy" />
</h:inputText>
```

That's using the built-in `component` object that references the current component (`<h:inputText>` in this case).

Focusing the first invalid component is very simple with that:

```
<h:outputScript>
    var firstInvalid = document.getElementsByClassName('invalidInput')[0];
    if (typeof firstInvalid !== 'undefined') firstInvalid.focus();
</h:outputScript>
```

There's also [another Example](http://mkblog.exadel.com/2011/05/how-to-hightlight-a-field-in-jsf-when-validation-fails/) by Max which works even when you can't get the `component` access to work.

Comment: Hi Mabi, thanks for the help.  Can you pls elaborate.  I 'm kinda new to JSF. Hope this doesn't bug you :).

Comment: used omnifaces but the jar was reject by application security. need to find other way out now :(

Comment: @user3115097 Sorry to hear that. Wouldn't want a JSF project w/o that library.

Comment: @user3115097 I've added a plain JSF2 example. Since your code still isn't valid - *are* you using JSF2? Or do you need to tag your question with `jsp`?